# Not able to use datepipe with locale format

Tags: angular, webpack, locale, date-formatting

I am building website using angular2 final and webpack cli. I have requirement to display date in locale nl-NL, my html code looks like:

```
{{eventDate | date:'d MMMM y'}}
```

it displays date like:

`5 January 2016`

It should display

`5 januari 2016`

any help will be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since RC6, there is an option to set default locale. You can do it in your `AppModule`, first you need to import `LOCALE_ID`:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you can change its default `us-US` value in your module's `providers`, in your case `nl-NL`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    bootstrap: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "nl-NL" }
    ]
})
```

Here's working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YRULhoEqurClE8G16TlC?p=preview

Comment: @MayurBhatt Glad I could help. If it's not a problem, consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the check-mark so people with similar problems will know that this solution is good. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for answer that is what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: Hot to set it on app load? or change it when user changes language?

Comment: If you run into the error "Missing locale data for local blah blah", then you need the following also in the app module. import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeNl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';
registerLocaleData(localeNl);